# Why is my a:link selector has priority over my "footer a:link" selector?

Tags: html, css

This is my website: [https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~yhao19/#academic_achievemnts](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Eyhao19/#academic_achievemnts)

For the footer, I wanted to have a darkgreen background with a white link color, but it seems that I can only change the color within my html file for it to work. My selector "footer a:link" does not select the link element and it seems that the a:link selector has priority over "footer a:link".

```
@import url("colors.css");

/*Global Styles
------------------------------------------------*/
body{
    color:#3A606E;
   
}

h1 {
    color:indianred;
}

h2{
    color: indianred;
}

h3{
    color: darksalmon;
}

h4{
    color: peachpuff;
}


a:active{
    color: var(--lightRed);
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:link{
    color:var(--darkRed);
}
/*li, pre, label{
    
}*/



/*About Me 
------------------------------------------------*/
#about_me{
    
    
}

/*Profile
------------------------------------------------*/
#profile{
    background-color: var(--darkRed);
    color: var(--whiteText);
}

#profile, a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Projects 
------------------------------------------------*/
#projects{
    background-color: var(--lightGreen)  ;

}

/*Work Experience 
------------------------------------------------*/
#work_experiences{
    background-color: var(--lightRed);

}

/*Drawings and Paintigs
------------------------------------------------*/
#drawings_paintings{

}

/*Footer
------------------------------------------------*/
footer{
    background-color: var(--darkGreen) ;
    color: var(--whiteText);
    
}


footer a:link{
    color:seashell;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This is my html footer code:

```
<footer>
    <a style="color:seashell"; href="#toc">Back to the table 
of contents</a>
    <a href="https://www.mcgill.ca/">McGill University</a>
</footer>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I'm so sorry, it's my first post. Now the code has been added : )

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the color change inline in HTML works and the CSS one doesnt is because the `a:link` selector refers to the link before its clicked just like `a:hover` refers to a link over which you're hovering with your mouse.

Meaning if i understand your intention correctly you meant to use the `footer a` selector as this is what refers to the link

Long story short use this:

```
footer a {
    color:seashell;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Actually it worked 20mins after I have refreshed the page. Thank you anyway tho !